# Why can't I add flatpak repos?

Tags: linux, fedora, flatpak

In order to install Element on Fedora (36) I tried to follow some tutorials, all instructing me to install `flatpak` and set up a remote:

```
flatpak remote-add [--if-not-exists] flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

I tried it with and without `sudo` but `im.riot.Riot` can't be found or installed and `flatpak remotes` always gives me

```
$ flatpak remotes
Name   Options
fedora system,oci
```

Without `--if-not-exists` I get `error: Remote flathub already exists`.

Also `[sudo] flatpak [--user] repair` didn't help.

What are my options?

**Update**: also I tried to grep for `flathub` below `.local/share/flatpak` and `/etc/flatpak` - but with no findings..
Also `/etc/flatpak/remotes.d/` and `./.local/share/flatpak/repo/refs/remotes` are both empty..

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it. For some strange reasons `flathub` seems to have been installed before but set to `disabled` in  `/var/lib/flatpak/repo/config`

```
[remote "flathub"]
url=https://dl.flathub.org/repo/
xa.title=Fedora Flathub Selection
...
xa.description-is-set=true
xa.disable=true
```

Removing this line helped me, but another way would have been to just add the repo as user:

```
flatpak  remote-add --user flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```